# How and why bodies with great masses alter time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass

*I am dreadfully sorry for any mistake in jargon.*

Theory of relativity, or so the interpretations of which I was merry to read; states that great masses get to alter, and this is where I get confused, 'the fabric of time'.

Is this true as to be taken literally? That masses with great bodies bend the time so that it functions differently for those inside the boundaries of that great mass than those who aren't?

Or is it merely an illusion exclusively for those outside of the 'bended fabric'?

To explain myself more adequately; for three human beings, one from Earth, the other travelling intergalactic emptiness, and the third inside the orbit of a great mass (or any mass greater than Earth, granted it not being a black-hole to keep Physics as we know it apply) are all granted a clock that is precise to the most  peculiar difference. Let's assume there happens an earthquake at 10 passed 9 earth time;

A) Moment the quake started , would the clocks of all 3 individuals show 10 passed 9?

B) Regardless what the clock says, by earth time 10 passed 9, did that event occur at any point in the universe (that is to say, for the human near a great body of mass,say 10 passed 9 hit's 5 minutes later than Earth time, that event will not going to 'rehappen' and that the action of quake occurred, and already ended.)

C) As our Earth is also a great body, are we also effected by this 'alteration of time' and if so, how much the time may differ to the human travelling in intergalactic harmony, compared to us in our planet?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, gravity affects time. See http://leapsecond.com/great2005/

Comment: Wikipedia: [Gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation)

Comment: Wikipedia: [Pound–Rebka experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound–Rebka_experiment)

Comment: *great masses … alter … time* So do tiny masses, according to theory. And it’s actually the density and flow of energy and momentum that cause spacetime curvature.

Comment: Don't ask what time is shown on different clocks when the owners of those clocks perceive a single event. Ask about _two_ events, and ask how much time each of the clocks says elapsed _between_ the two events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this true as to be taken literally? That masses with great bodies bend the time so that it functions differently for those inside the boundaries of that great mass than those who aren't?

It is spacetime, not just time, but yes this is literal. The geometry of spacetime is literally curved. Straight lines can intersect twice, triangles can have more or less than 180 degrees, etc.

> A) Moment the quake started , would the clocks of all 3 individuals show 10 passed 9?

There is no “natural” answer to this question, because the concept of a “moment” is not part of nature. It depends on your synchronization convention, which can be rather arbitrary.

> B) Regardless what the clock says, by earth time 10 passed 9, did that event occur at any point in the universe (that is to say, for the human near a great body of mass,say 10 passed 9 hit's 5 minutes later than Earth time, that event will not going to 'rehappen' and that the action of quake occurred, and already ended.)

It will not re-happen. There is a lot of flexibility in assigning coordinates to spacetime. But one restriction is that a coordinate chart must be an invertible mapping between the spacetime and the coordinates. So one event in spacetime must correspond to at most one coordinate point in a given chart.

> C) As our Earth is also a great body, are we also effected by this 'alteration of time' and if so, how much the time may differ to the human travelling in intergalactic harmony, compared to us in our planet?

Yes. At sea level the gravitational time dilation on earth is about 1 second every 46 years.

Comment: "Yes. At sea level the gravitational time dilation on earth is about 1 second every 46 years." Absolutely fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

A simple (and not rigorous) way of thinking about this is to imagine 4-dimensional spacetime getting "bunched up" in the vicinity of large masses. Spacetime is incredibly "stiff" and resistant to such bunching; it takes *the entire mass of the earth* to bunch up spacetime enough to make you weigh ~150 pounds and to make a clock run one second slow in 46 years, as Dale points out.

Richard Feynman once stated that this bunching up amounts to around 1/4" at the earth's equator, out of ~27,000 miles of circumference.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at curvature is that two apparent symmetric paths don't form a closed loop.

Suppose you're in the basement lab with 2 atomic clocks ($A$ and $B$), both starting at the same radius (wrt to the center of the earth), and the same time. Then $A$ is transported to the top of the building (say 100 meters), and they both tick-off, well, let's choose 46 years.

After 46 years, the basement clock, $B$, is transported to the top floor. It arrives one second late, according the clock $A$.

So each clock moved radially outward 100 meters, and forward in time 46 years, but the spacetime locations of their endpoints differ by one second. This is analogous to 2 ppl walking, starting at the equator:

1. 100 km due north, and then 100 km due east (but remains on a great circle)
2. 100 km due east, and the 100 km due north.

They'll wind up about 17 meters apart.

Comment: This is not an illusion or anything right, or the effect the mass has on the clock or any other body. Really with all the same measures time *flows* slower?